# Pass enum as a parameter in C# or any alternatives

Tags: c#, enums

```
public EnumA
{
name = 1,
surname = 2
}
public EnumB
{
name = 50,
surname = 60
}

public void myMethod(User u,Enum e)
{
//Enum e can be either EnumA or EnumB
//Do something with the Enum Passed
}
```

Let's say I have the above code but instead of specifiying the Enum in the method like I'm doing above, I'd like to select the enum which is passed through the method parameter. Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: Can you give more of an example about what output your would like to see, and how you are calling `myMethod`?  I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish yet.

Comment: @BradleyUffner According to which Enum is passed through I want to get all the Enum values

Comment: Do all of your enums have `name` and `surname` members?

Comment: Why do you have two enums carrying the same information? Also, do you have a real world example of what youre trying to achieve so that we can give you the best help

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via reflection, but I'm worried that you don't understand enumerations properly.  It kind of looks to me like you are trying to use them as class instances to hold arbitrary data, in which case, you really should be using a real `class`.

In case I'm wrong, I've included code below to do what you are asking for, but I don't think it will be very useful for you.

```
void Main()
{
    Test(EnumA.First);
    Console.WriteLine("-----");
    Test(EnumB.B);
}

void Test(Enum theEnum)
{
    Type t = theEnum.GetType();
    foreach (string element in Enum.GetNames(t))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(element + " = " + (int) Enum.Parse(t, element));
    }
}

enum EnumA
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2
}

enum EnumB
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3
}
```

It generates the following output:

```
First = 1
Second = 2
-----
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
```

---

I **think** this is more what you are trying to do though:

```
void Main()
{
    Person A = new Person()
    {
        Name = "John",
        Surname = "Doe"
    };

    Person B = new Person()
    {
        Name = "Jane",
        Surname = "Doe"
    };

    A.ShowInfo();
    Console.WriteLine("----");
    B.ShowInfo();
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public void ShowInfo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Name=" + Name);
        Debug.WriteLine("Surname=" + Surname);
    }
}
```

It output the following:

```
Name=John
Surname=Doe
----
Name=Jane
Surname=Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
public void myMethod(User u,Enum e)
{
    if (e is EnumA)
    {
        EnumA ea = (EnumA)e;
        // Do something with ea
    }
    else if (e is EnumB)
    {
        EnumB eb = (EnumB)e;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work but what if I had way too many Enums (which is not practical but that's the solution I'm working on at)

Comment: If you had so many enums then you're doing it wrong. I can't even see a reason for the enum's you've provided in your sample. You know that there are "flags" enums?

Answer (score 0):

you have use generic type for this operation.

below code is showing a sample code (as Console app);

```c#
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myMethod<EnumA>("deneme", EnumA.name);
        }

        public enum EnumA
        {
            name = 1,
            surname = 2
        }
        public enum EnumB
        {
            name = 50,
            surname = 60
        }

        public static void myMethod<T>(string u, T e)
            where T : struct,IConvertible
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(EnumA))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EnumA");
            }
           else if (typeof(T) == typeof(EnumB))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EnumB");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use overloading:

```
public void myMethod(User u, EnumA e)
{
  // Call a function common to both
}


public void myMethod(User u, EnumB e)
{
  // Call a function common to both
}
```

I guess C# 7.3 allows you to do something like:

```
public void myMethod(User u, TEnum e) where TEnum : Enum
{
  //Enum e can be either EnumA or EnumB
  //Do something with the Enum Passed
}
```

I used something like this for a pre-7.3 project and it was a little ugly, but WAY better and more readable than any other way I could find:

```
public void myMethod(User u, object e)
{
  // Test to make sure object type is either EnumA or EnumB
  // Call a function common to both
  // object e can be either EnumA or EnumB by casting like ((EnumA)e) or ((EnumB)e)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not how enums behave (or should behave). You're basically creating two different instances of enums. This is why classes exist in C#. Consider creating a class:

```
public class SomeEnum
{
    public int Name;
    public int Surname;

    private SomeEnum(int name, int surname)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public static SomeEnum EnumA => new SomeEnum(1, 2);
    public static SomeEnum EnumB => new SomeEnum(50, 60);
}
```

And changing your method to this:

```
public void myMethod(User u, SomeEnum e)
{
  // Enum e can be either EnumA or EnumB
  // Do something with the Enum passed
}
```

I changed as least code as possible as I'm not sure what the purpose is of these 'Enums', but this way you'll be able to create as many instances as you want, without your code getting messy with all of these identical Enum specifications.

To use this method with EnumA for example you can call `myMethod(user, SomeEnum.EnumA)`.

This way it's only possible to use the specified enums (`EnumA` and `EnumB`). Alternatively, if you want to create enums on-the-fly, the code can be changed to:

```
public class SomeEnum
{
    public int Name;
    public int Surname;

    public SomeEnum(int name, int surname)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
    }
}
```

This way you can call the method with `myMethod(user, new SomeEnum(1, 2))`.